# Scroll to center of UIScrollview clicked UIButton added programmatically EDITED

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I  have a scrollview of scrollview of UIbuttons build like this:

```
-(void) loadCompeticionSlide{

    float x=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [categoriasArray count]; i++) {

        NSDictionary *categoria = [categoriasArray objectAtIndex:i];

        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        NSString *titleString  = [categoria valueForKey:@"competicion"];  // get button title

        btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];

        CGSize fontSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0]];

        CGRect currentFrame = btn.frame;

        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(x, currentFrame.origin.y, fontSize.width + 22.0, fontSize.height + 12.0);

        [btn setFrame:buttonFrame];

        x = x + fontSize.width + 35.0;

        [btn setTitle:titleString forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        int idc = [[categoria valueForKey:@"idc"]intValue];

         [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(cambiarCompeticion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         [btn setTag:idc];

        [self.competicionSlide addSubview:btn];

    }

    //[competicionSlide setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    competicionSlide.contentSize = CGSizeMake(350,35);
    competicionSlide.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
    competicionSlide.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}
```

Then, in the added selector cambiarCompeticion:, I got the button clicked, here I need to use scrollRectToVisible: to get the clicked UIButton scrolled to the center of the UIScrollview that contains it, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the selector method triggered by button selection where I understand scrollRectToVisible: has to be called:

```
-(void)cambiarCompeticion:(UIButton*)boton{

    int idCompeticion;

    idCompeticion = boton.tag;

    switch (idCompeticion) {
        case 1:
            [self tablaLigaRegular];
            break;

        case 5:
            [self tablaCoparey];
            break;

        case 10:
            [self tablaPlayOff];
            break;    

           }


}
```

here are the details in images, in first image blue arrow indicates previous state of the partial hidden left button and the move to do to the middle of scroll view once it is clicked:

[image]

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **boton** parameter (from the *cambiarCompeticion:* selector) has everything you need. Just call like this (assuming that "competicionSlide" is an UIScrollView) :

```
[self.competicionSlide scrollRectToVisible:boton.frame];
```

Good luck !

Comment: thanks Darkbyte, I've tried it, but scroll is not moving. Any suggestion?

Comment: I re-read your question and I'm not so sure anymore of what you need. A few questions:

All your buttons are visible (no need to scroll to see them all) ?

What exactly do you mean when you say that you want the UIButton to "get scrolled to the center of the ScrollView" ? Do you want to animate the button into another position ... or scroll the entire scroll view?

Comment: No, they are not all visible. I mean once user clicks for instance, a button is in the right side of visible scrollview , scrollview will scroll and left button in the middle of the scrollview. And the same if button is in the left side. I will add an explanation image in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed something in your code:

    competicionSlide.contentSize = CGSizeMake(350,35);

Shouldn't your ScrollView width be larger ? The combined width of the buttons, the spaces between the buttons and some space on both left and right ?

Try this one, and then see if `scrollRectToVisible:` moves the ScrollView.

Comment: I have changed it, but your suggestion ring the bell, the buttons I try to scroll to center are not hidden, so scrollRectToVisible: is not executed because buttons are visible, but not centered. Thanks!

Comment: Good point. I'm glad I made you see your problem, if not solve it :)